# Copy/update SharePoint list with lookup

Tags: sharepoint-online

I try copy list from one site to another using template, but this list contains lookup fields. Is there any way copy lists without breaking this fields? I copy all lists which will be used for lookup links.An d another question, i have equal lists in two different site collections, i need update data in second list using first, how better do that?

Comment: i think about using powershell but i don't have appropriate permissions. And now i think about Client Model. Anybody know such way, using Client Model?

Answer (score 0):

Saving list as template will not keep the look up field connections.

Workaround is

1. Restore Lookup Lists in Destination
2. Save Master List as Template without data
3. Restore Master List in Destination
4. Fix Lookup fields
5. Export source list into Excel
6. Copy Rows from Excel
7. Open Destination List in Data Sheet mode
8. Paste data